Injective hull and change of rings
Let $M$ be a module over a commutative Noetherian ring $R$. Let $E_R(M)$ be the injective envelope of $M$. Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. I can clearly see that Hom$_R(R/I, M)$ embeds in the injective $R/I$-module Hom$_R(R/I, E_R(M))$. My question is:

Is Hom$_R(R/I, E_R(M))$ the injective envelope of Hom$_R(R/I, M)$ in the category of $R/I$-modules?


I will just treat $M$ as a submodule of $E:=E_R(M)$. All there is to show is that $(0:_{M} I)\subseteq (0:_{E} I)$ is an essential extension. Let $f\in (0:_E I)$. Since $E$ is an essential extension of $M$, there exists $r\in R$ such that $0\neq rf\in M$. It is clear that $rf\in (0:_M I)$.
